# Are Stonean spaces a reflective subcategory of topological spaces with continuous open maps?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, boolean-algebra

**I'm not talking about Stone spaces!** A Stonean space is a compact Hausdorff [extremally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space) space i.e. a compact Hausdorff space such that for all open $U$, its closure $\overline{U}$ is also open.

I've been thinking about applications of [regular open sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_open_set) in topology, and I came up with the following:

If $X$ is a topological space then the set $\text{RO}(X)$ of regular open sets of $X$ forms a complete Boolean algebra. This Boolean algebra induces a Stonean space $S(X)$ by [Stone duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras). Thus to any topological space we can assign a Stonean space $S(X)$.

If $X$ is a Stonean space, then $\text{RO}(X)$ is a Boolean algebra of clopen sets of $X$, so that Stone duality tells us $S(X)$ gives us $X$ back.

If $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map, then $f^{-1}(\text{RO}(Y))\subseteq \text{RO}(X)$ is not true in general (see comments below). Thus I want to restrict to continuous open maps. In this case, if $U\in\text{RO}(Y)$ then $$\text{int }\overline{f^{-1}(U)} = \text{int }f^{-1}(\overline{U}) = f^{-1}(\text{int }\overline{U})$$ see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565434/characterizing-continuous-open-and-closed-maps-via-interior-and-closure-operato) by Paul Frost. So $f^{-1}$ induces a map from $\text{RO}(Y)$ to $\text{RO}(X)$. Then the Stone duality induces a map $S(f):S(X)\to S(Y)$.

Now, using this, does that mean that Stonean spaces are a [reflective subcategory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory) of topological spaces with continuous open maps?

Comment: Do you mean for the morphisms of Stonean spaces to be all continuous functions? Those would correspond to arbitrary Boolean homomorphisms, not complete homomorphisms.

Comment: @EricWofsey yes, because I want the subcategory to be full

Comment: @Jakobian: If $X,Y$ are topological spaces and $f\colon X\to Y$ continuous and $U$ is a regular open subset of $Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ does not have to be regular open in $X$.  For example $f(x)=x^2$ on $\Bbb{R}$.  Then $f^{-1}((0,+\infty))=(-\infty,0)\sqcup(0,\infty)$ which is not regular open.  The map $f^{-1}$ [does not](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3570780) even preserve the Heyting-algebra structure on the open sets of $Y$.

Comment: @ChadK are you saying that we should use continuous open maps on the category of Stonean spaces in order to establish meaningful results?

Comment: @Jakobian:  I don't know what the functor is.  You're implying there's a functor, but you only said what the functor does to objects, not to maps.

Comment: @ChadK I've realized that I do want them to be continuous and open, thank you.

Comment: @Jakobian: See Andrew M. Gleason "Projective Topological Spaces", May 1958, Theorem 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Stonean spaces are not reflective in all topological spaces with continuous open maps.  Consider an arbitrary Stone space $X$.  Note that every continuous map $X\to\{0,1\}$ is automatically open.  So, if a reflection $i:X\to Y$ of $X$ into Stonean spaces existed, every continuous map $X\to\{0,1\}$ would factor through $i$ and so $i$ would be injective since these maps separate points of $X$.  But since $i$ is open and $X$ is compact, this would mean that $i$ is an embedding of $X$ as a clopen subspace of $Y$, so $X$ itself must be Stonean.  So any non-Stonean Stone space does not have a Stonean reflection.

(The problem with the construction you propose is that there is not actually a canonical continuous open map $X\to S(X)$.  Very concretely, a point of $S(X)$ is an ultrafilter on $RO(X)$.  But a point of $X$ doesn't naturally give an ultrafilter on $RO(X)$, since if $U\in RO(X)$, then $U$ and its complement in $RO(X)$ may not actually cover all of $X$, so the filter on $RO(X)$ given by which regular open sets contain a given point of $X$ may not be an ultrafilter.)